# How to do XSS escaping on input coming into Restlet web service

Tags: rest, gwt, xss, restlet

I have a GWT web application using Restlet.

It has @Post annotated service methods that take a bean and perform some logic on it.

I want to XML-escape the data in these beans.

For example, say I have the following:

```java
public class MyService extends ServerResource {
    @Post
    public DataBean performLogic(DataBean bean) {
       ...
    }
}

public class DataBean {
    String data;
}
```

Is there a way I could XML-escape `DataBean.data` after it's serialized but before it is sent to `MyService.performLogic()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the doInit() method, this may allow you do do what you need; but will occur before any calls to your @Post @Get method in your ServerResource.

Alternatively if you need it more widely you may want to look at adding a Filter into your Command Chain and overriding the beforeHandle() method there.

Comment: How would I modify the bean in doInit()? Or the request data that is used to create the bean?

Comment: It was my belief that you would be looking to modify the data before it is extracted into the bean Representation.  However getRequest().getEntity() should return it to you.  However be careful this may be readOnce.